# Xamarin UI Test shows redundant logs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, log4net

I'm using Visual Studio, Windows 7, Xamarin.UITest and log4net.
When i'm launching autotests i see a lot of logs and i don't know how to turn off them. Actually, i even not sure are these logs generated by log4net or not. Because when I try to turn off log4net

```
<log4net threshold="OFF" />
```

I still see such logs:

```
Test Name:  RunTest
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:  
Full log file: C:\Users\a.matsyuk.ITRANSITION\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\log-2016-10-10_12-34-08-716.txt

Potential Android SDK location: C:\Users\a.matsyuk.ITRANSITION\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk - Valid SDK. [ Source: ANDROID_HOME ]
Potential Android SDK location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk - Valid SDK. [ Source: Registry ]
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\a.matsyuk.ITRANSITION\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Using JDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73 [ Source: JAVA_HOME ]
Skipping IDE integration as important properties are configured. To force IDE integration, add .PreferIdeSettings() to ConfigureApp.
Finished with exit code 0 in 58 ms.
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=2)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0xa2
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="2.5.3" (Raw: "2.5.3")
    A: android:installLocation(0x010102b7)=(type 0x10)0x0
    A: package="com.CarbonForms" (Raw: "com.CarbonForms")
    A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x17 (Raw: "23")
    A: platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002" (Raw: "6.0-2704002")
    E: uses-sdk (line=3)
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x13
      A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x17
    E: uses-permission (line=4)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
    E: uses-permission (line=5)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE")
    E: uses-permission (line=6)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
    E: uses-permission (line=7)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA")
    E: uses-permission (line=8)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=9)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=10)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA")
    E: uses-permission (line=11)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" (Raw: "android.permission.BATTERY_STATS")
    E: uses-permission (line=12)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_LOGS" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_LOGS")
    E: uses-permission (line=13)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE")
    E: uses-permission (line=14)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" (Raw: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH")
    E: uses-permission (line=15)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.microsoft.band.service.access.BIND_BAND_SERVICE"
```

...

```
Forwarded port 58278.
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:21 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:22 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:22 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:22 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:23 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:23 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:23 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:23 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
HTTP POST { Url: { AbsolutePath: "/map", AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", LocalPath: "/map", Authority: "127.0.0.1:58278", HostNameType: IPv4, IsDefaultPort: False, IsFile: False, IsLoopback: True, PathAndQuery: "/map", Segments: [ "/", "map" ], IsUnc: False, Host: "127.0.0.1", Port: 58278, Query: "", Fragment: "", Scheme: "http", OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:58278/map", DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1", IdnHost: "127.0.0.1", IsAbsoluteUri: True, UserEscaped: False, UserInfo: "" } }
POST Complete { StatusCode: OK, StatusDescription: "OK ", ResponseHeaders: "Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 09:34:24 GMT
", Contents: "{"results":[{"class":"com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView","tag":null,"description":"com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1a9c4837 V.ED.... R....... 0,0-1080,1776}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":1776,"width":1080,"y":0,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":888},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{18a812b8 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1776}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":1776,"width":1080,"y":0,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":888},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.FrameLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.FrameLayout{3bbe3068 V.E..... ........ 0,75-1080,1776 #1020002 android:id/content}","id":"content","visible":true,"rect":{"height":1701,"width":1080,"y":75,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":925},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{1bc15aea V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1701}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":1701,"width":1080,"y":75,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":925},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{2c128398 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1701}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":1701,"width":1080,"y":75,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":925},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.ListView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.ListView{27943891 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-1080,1701 #102000a android:id/list}","id":"list","visible":true,"rect":{"height":1701,"width":1080,"y":75,"x":0,"center_x":540,"center_y":925},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{147e73f6 V.E..... ..S..... 48,0-1032,192}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":984,"y":75,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":171},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{277083f7 V.E..... ..S..... 24,13-810,179}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":166,"width":786,"y":88,"x":72,"center_x":465,"center_y":171},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{1b27a264 V.ED.... ..S..... 0,18-611,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Server protocol, use https","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":611,"y":106,"x":72,"center_x":377,"center_y":142},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{20b2cccd V.ED.... ..S..... 0,91-286,148 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"Tick to use SSL","visible":true,"rect":{"height":57,"width":286,"y":179,"x":72,"center_x":215,"center_y":207},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{1a15d982 V.E..... ..S..... 810,0-954,192 #1020018 android:id/widget_frame}","id":"widget_frame","visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":144,"y":75,"x":858,"center_x":930,"center_y":171},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.CheckBox","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.CheckBox{1f6893 V.ED.... ..S..... 24,48-120,144 #1020001 android:id/checkbox}","id":"checkbox","text":"","visible":true,"rect":{"height":96,"width":96,"y":123,"x":882,"center_x":930,"center_y":171},"enabled":true,"checked":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{13ee80d0 V.E..... ........ 48,194-1032,386}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":984,"y":269,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":365},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{18ac68c9 V.E..... ........ 24,13-954,179}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":166,"width":930,"y":282,"x":72,"center_x":537,"center_y":365},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{1dcc0bce V.ED.... ........ 0,18-421,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Server Ip Address","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":421,"y":300,"x":72,"center_x":282,"center_y":336},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{acdfaef V.ED.... ........ 0,91-281,148 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"eg 10.20.19.82","visible":true,"rect":{"height":57,"width":281,"y":373,"x":72,"center_x":212,"center_y":401},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{2002d9fc V.E..... ........ 48,388-1032,580}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":984,"y":463,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":559},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{1489c885 V.E..... ........ 24,13-954,179}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":166,"width":930,"y":476,"x":72,"center_x":537,"center_y":559},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{15a116da V.ED.... ........ 0,18-464,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Server WebApi Port","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":464,"y":494,"x":72,"center_x":304,"center_y":530},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{1129570b V.ED.... ........ 0,91-193,148 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"eg 80/443","visible":true,"rect":{"height":57,"width":193,"y":567,"x":72,"center_x":168,"center_y":595},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{4a199e8 V.E..... ........ 48,582-1032,774}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":984,"y":657,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":753},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{27236801 V.E..... ........ 24,13-954,179}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":166,"width":930,"y":670,"x":72,"center_x":537,"center_y":753},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{2589c6a6 V.ED.... ........ 0,18-489,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Server Gateway Port","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":489,"y":688,"x":72,"center_x":316,"center_y":724},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{9458e7 V.ED.... ........ 0,91-128,148 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"eg 903","visible":true,"rect":{"height":57,"width":128,"y":761,"x":72,"center_x":136,"center_y":789},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{1bea6c94 V.E..... ........ 48,776-1032,991}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":215,"width":984,"y":851,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":958},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{1e5d833d V.E..... ........ 24,0-954,215}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":215,"width":930,"y":851,"x":72,"center_x":537,"center_y":958},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{29fba732 V.ED.... ........ 0,18-442,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Business Function","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":442,"y":869,"x":72,"center_x":293,"center_y":905},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{fc39c83 V.ED.... ........ 0,91-906,197 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"The business function that governs how the app behaves","visible":true,"rect":{"height":106,"width":906,"y":942,"x":72,"center_x":525,"center_y":995},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.LinearLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.LinearLayout{204bbe00 V.E..... ........ 48,993-1032,1185}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":192,"width":984,"y":1068,"x":48,"center_x":540,"center_y":1164},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.RelativeLayout","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.RelativeLayout{8241639 V.E..... ........ 24,13-954,179}","id":null,"visible":true,"rect":{"height":166,"width":930,"y":1081,"x":72,"center_x":537,"center_y":1164},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{1f39047e V.ED.... ........ 0,18-617,91 #1020016 android:id/title}","id":"title","text":"Business Operation Mode","visible":true,"rect":{"height":73,"width":617,"y":1099,"x":72,"center_x":380,"center_y":1135},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null},{"class":"android.widget.TextView","tag":null,"description":"android.widget.TextView{22197ddf V.ED.... ........ 0,91-726,148 #1020010 android:id/summary}","id":"summary","text":"The business mode the app shall run in","visible":true,"rect":{"height":57,"width":726,"y":1172,"x":72,"center_x":435,"center_y":1200},"enabled":true,"contentDescription":null}],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}" }
```

**Here is my app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TargetPlatform" value="android" />
    <add key="ApplicationPath" value="D:/_xamarin/test.apk" />
    <add key="WaitTimeoutSeconds" value="60" />
    <add key="WaitConnectionTimeoutSeconds" value="180" />
  </appSettings>
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level  - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="fileApp" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="LogFile.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="Console" />
      <appender-ref ref="fileApp" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
<system.data><DbProviderFactories><remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" /><add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /></DbProviderFactories></system.data><runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><publisherPolicy apply="no" /><assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime><oracle.manageddataaccess.client><version number="*"><dataSources><dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " /></dataSources></version></oracle.manageddataaccess.client></configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Those logs are not caused by log4net. These entries are the Debug logging from UItests. You can turn them off by changing how you configure your app in the AppInitializer. It stopped outputting all the extra information when I changed:
`ConfigureApp.Android.Debug().ApkFile(PathToAPK).StartApp();`
to 
`ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(PathToAPK).StartApp();` 
The summary for Debug() in AndroidAppConfigurator is " Enables debug logging from the test runner."